# Sencha Touch v2 Zoom Layout Issue

Tags: layout, touch, zooming, extjs

I'm having trouble with trying to get a really simple zooming example going with the v2 Sencha Touch Framework (RC). I've played around with several different layout types, and combinations of it, but it seems that the scrollers size is not updating, or the actual div representing the image is not expanding in order to be panned around? The be honest I'm at a total loss at the moment!!

```
var testImage = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
  src: 'images/Food/2.jpg'
});

Ext.Viewport.add({
  layout: 'card',
  scrollable: {
    direction: 'both',
    directionLock: false
  },
  items: [testImage]
});

Ext.Viewport.element.on({
  doubletap: function(e , node, options, eOpts) {
    var transformDetails = { scale: 2, angle: 0 };
    testImage.element.setStyle('-webkit-transform', 'scaleX(' + transformDetails.scale + ') scaleY(' + transformDetails.scale + ') rotate(' + transformDetails.angle + 'deg)');
  }
});
```

Does anybody have any insight on how to get this very simple example to correctly pan around once the scale is applied to the image? Feeling pretty incompetent at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

If you add these lines to code, you are able to do events like pan, zoom and pinch.

```
Ext.Viewport.setPreventPanning(false);
Ext.Viewport.setPreventZooming(false);
```